# C++: Does ios::out replace the file with a new one or destoys the content of the file?

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Assume i have  `out.txt` containing the text `Hello World`

If i do this

`fstream ("out.txt" , ios::out)`

Then if i try to open the file it will be empty.

My question is when i open a file stream to a file with the `ios::out` flag

The file is empty yes.

But did it go inside the file and delete all its contents

or did it create a new empty file and overwrote the old one?

Comment: It doesn't really matter because the difference is not observable in C++.

Comment: Have you tried searching for  ios::out in google ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's up to the operating system.

Some keep versioned generations of each file. In that case, you will likely get a new one each time.

Comment: Correct.  The C++ standard refers to the C standard---`ios::out` corresponds to `"w"`.  And the C standard says "Truncate to zero length or create file for writing".  Both solutions are acceptable as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: Then why when i check the creation date of the file it is still the same

Comment: @Mohammed - Then *on your system* it seems like the file is truncated. Doesn't have to be that way everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same file with its content erased. In order to append to the file you have to use `ios::app`

Comment: There is a difference between the same file name and the same file

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil it used the same file, it didn't create a new one.

Comment: how can you tell, It can create a new one with the same file name and overwrite the old one

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil that's the point: you can't tell the difference.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil you can't tell, I'm just going by what the books told me.

Answer (score 2):

It should truncate the file, meaning keeping the same file entry, and only clearing the content.